# string method null is in other method's select query

Tags: ado.net

I am creating Student attendance info system.

These methods are related to each other as you can see.
`students` table has general info about each student.
Some students are always absent, so no students_ID in `register` table.
And this cause for an error with da.Fill(dt). It says :

> MySqlException was unhandled by user code "You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax;  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"

How can I eliminate this error?

```
private string getUquvchilar_ID()
{
    var fish = ddlName.Text.Replace("'", "''");
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string query = "Select Students_ID from students where CONCAT(Familiyasi , ' ', Ismi , ' ', Sharifi)='" + fish + "'";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    String s = (cmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? String.Empty).ToString();
    con.Close();
    return s;
}
private void BindGrid()
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM rasmlar where Rasm_ID in (" + String.Join(",", getImage_ID()) + ")", con);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    gvImages.DataSource = dt;
    gvImages.DataBind();
}
private List<int> getImage_ID()
{
    List<int> i = new List<int>();
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string query = "Select bosh_rasm_ID, Tugal_rasm_ID from register where students_ID='" + getUquvchilar_ID() + "'"; 
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
    {
        foreach (DbDataRecord s in reader)
        {
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("bosh_rasm_ID")))
                i.Add(s.GetInt32(0));
            else
                i.Add(0);
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Tugal_rasm_ID")))
                i.Add(s.GetInt32(1));
            else
                i.Add(0);
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if getImage_ID() returns an empty list the select statement will be `SELECT * FROM rasmlar where Rasm_ID in ()` ... that is an invalid sql statement ... you'll have to handle that case explicitly.